# Toggle input type="range" in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I have a 3-state togglable button. It's an input type=range, I need to write automatic test for my application. Can someone help me to find a way toggling the button in robot framework? Is there any keyword for doing such things?

Here is the code of my button:

```js
    function togglebutton(range) {

        var val = range.value;

        if (val == 1) {

            //change color of slider background
            range.className = "no";
            range.id = "radio-no";
            range.checked = true;

            //alter text
            document.getElementById('span-selector').setAttribute("class", "wrong");
            document.getElementById('label-selector').setAttribute("for", "radio-no");

        } else if (val == 2) {
            //change color of slider background
            range.className = "neutral";
            range.id = "radio-neutral";
            range.checked = true;

            //alter text
            document.getElementById('span-selector').setAttribute("class", "natural-icon");
            document.getElementById('label-selector').setAttribute("for", "radio-natural");

        } else if (val == 3) {
            //change color of slider background
            range.className = "yes";
            range.id = "radio-yes";
            range.checked = true;

            //alter text
            document.getElementById('span-selector').setAttribute("class", "correct");
            document.getElementById('label-selector').setAttribute("for", "radio-yes");
        }
    }
```

```css
.radio-wrapper {
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(114, 191, 68, 0.4);
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.correct {
    left: 15px;
    top: -5px;
}

.wrong {
    right: 17px;
    top: -5px;
}

.neutral-icon {
    left: 69px;
    top: -8px;
    opacity: .5;
}

label {
    z-index: 9;
}

input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

i {
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.neutral-icon i {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.neutral + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 37%;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.neutral::-moz-range-thumb, .no-style::-moz-range-thumb  {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238, 238, 238, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 100%);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.yes + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.yes::-moz-range-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(32, 213, 50);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(32, 213, 50, 1) 0%, rgba(28, 195, 1, 1) 100%);
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.no + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.no::-moz-range-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-name: slideno;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideno;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideno;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    background: rgb(230, 108, 103);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(230, 108, 103, 1) 0%, rgba(221, 79, 75, 1) 100%);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

@keyframes slidein {
    from {
        transform: translate(25px, 0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes slideno {
    from {
        transform: translate(-25px, 0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}

@keyframes returnLeft {
    from {
        transform: translate(-50px, 0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes returnRight {
    from {
        transform: translate(50px, 0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="pull-left"><?php echo Language::T('Confirm'); ?></span>
                    <span class="pull-right"><?php echo Language::T('Reject'); ?></span>
                    <div class="radio-wrapper">
                        <span id="span-selector"></span>
                        <?php if ($row['state'] == 0)
                        {
                            $state = 2;
                        }
                        elseif ($row['state'] == 1)
                        {
                            $state = 3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $state = 1;
                        } ?>
                        <input type="range" class="no-style" name="data[orderId][<?= $row['orderId'] ?>]"
                               onchange="togglebutton(this);"
                               min="1" max="3" value="<?= $state ? $state : 2 ?>">
                    </div>
```

Is there any keyword for doing such things?

Comment: Is there a value in the HTML that represents what the state is?

Comment: I'll edit my question and place my HTML code.

Comment: Have you tried using `Execute Javascript` to call `togglebutton(range)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your HTML you must have either an absolute or relative path to your JavaScript file. If you can obtain an absolute path, then this becomes fairly simple.

Because I don't know your absolute path, I'll assume the .js file is stored on your local machine and I'll assume the path (in Robot Framework syntax) is `C:/Users/user01/Desktop/javascriptcode.js`.

Robot Framework has a keyword called `Execute JavaScript`. It runs a line of JavaScript, exactly what it says on the can. It can return a value, but that's not important to this answer.

You'll want to use the full path to not only the file name, but also the exact method in the file, as follows:

```
Execute JavaScript  C:/Users/user01/Desktop/javascriptcode.js.togglebutton(${range})
```

That will send the value of the variable `${range}` to your `togglebutton()` function, triggering the code inside it to run and toggle your switch.